# Error while trying to build a send button

Tags: swift, firebase

I'm currently trying to build a chat feature, but I get some errors when trying to implement a send button. The errors I get are: 
**

> Binary operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'UITextField?' 'String'

and

> Value of type 'DataService' has no member 'createNewMessage'

My code:

```
@IBAction func sendButton(_ sender: Any) {
    self.chatTextfield.resignFirstResponder()
    if chatTextfield != "" {
        if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser {
            DataService.dataService.createNewMessage(user.uid, roomId: roomId, textMessage: chatTextfield.text!)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the `DataService` class a Firebase class?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri yes

Comment: Is there any documentation for that?

Comment: I tried writing DataService.dataservice. but only createNewRoom showed up and not createNewMessage

Comment: There is no class in the Firebase SDK that has `createNewMessage` and/or `createNewRoom` methods, so it seems that you created this class yourself or copied it from somewhere. I recommend opening a new question for this problem (since Rakesha already answered for your other question), and creating a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link please, it's quite useful when asking for help with code-related questions) in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error is because you are comparing `UITextField` object with a `String`. You should be comparing the text in the text field instead.

```
if chatTextfield.text != "" {
    // do something
}
```

Or in a more *Swifty* way, like this,

```
if !chatTextfield.text!.isEmpty {
    // do something
}
```

My knowledge in Firebase is next to none. So, i can't help you much with the second one. From the error, it is pretty clear that there is no method by that name. So, if you just got the method signature wrong, you should write `DataService.dataService.` and let firebase show you suggestions and pick the appropriate one.

Comment: thank you! the first problem got solved. I tried the DataService.dataService. but only createNewRoom showed up and not CreateNewMessage

Comment: @potatoonion where did you see this `createNewMessage` method?

Comment: I read somewhere yesterday night that's how to create a message guess it was wrong, is there another way to create a message?

Comment: I'm not familiar with firebase. You should look up their documentation.

Comment: yea same, I'm kinda new to firebase too. I don't seem to still understand their documentation about creating new message tho :(